# Требуются ли запятые в данных предложениях?

Tags: пунктуация

Нужны ли здесь запятые или нет? Почему?

На двенадцатый день, при отличной учебе, вы получите хорошую оценку.

Они узнали, кто я такой, после того, как познакомился с ними.

Он работает как положено.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*На двенадцатый день при отличной учебе вы получите хорошую оценку.* Нет причин для постановки запятых.

*Они узнали, кто я такой, после того как познакомился с ними.* Сложный подчинительный союз "после того как" не расчленяется.

*Он работает как положено.* Запятой нет, оборот тесно связан со сказуемым.